# smil to javascript for IE support

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to port the animate in svg(SMIL) to javacript because SMIL is unsupported by IE. Any pointers to how to port the animate svg tag to javascript.
Here is the SMIL:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <svg class="splash-content-spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 28 28"  width="28" height="28">
    <path d="M1.5,13 A12.5,12.5 0 0,1 12.5,1.5" style="fill: none; stroke: #d8baf1;  stroke-width: 3;"> 
    <animate id="c1" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS"  begin="0s;c4.end" dur="200ms" from="#d8baf1" to="#9d52dc" />
    </path>
     <path d="M15,1.5 A12.5,12.5 0 0,1 26.5,13" style="fill: none;stroke: #d8baf1;stroke-width: 3;">
    <animate id="c2" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS"  begin="c1.end" dur="200ms" from="#d8baf1" to="#9d52dc" />
    </path>
      <path d="M26.5,15 A12.5,12.5 0 0,1 15,26.5" style="fill: none;stroke:#d8baf1;stroke-width: 3;">
    <animate id="c3" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS"  begin="c2.end" dur="200ms" from="#d8baf1" to="#9d52dc" />
    </path> 
       <path d="M13,26.5 A12.5,12.5 0 0,1 1.5,15" style="fill: none;stroke: #d8baf1;stroke-width: 3;">
    <animate id="c4" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS"  begin="c3.end" dur="200ms" from="#d8baf1" to="#9d52dc" />  
    </path>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use fakeSmile, then IE will run the SMIL without you needing to change the code. https://leunen.me/fakesmile/

Comment: fakesmile cannot be used because it instantiates an activex object and asks for permission.

Comment: You could replace      request = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") : null; with request = new XMLHttpRequest(); to fix that